# Measure cache line utilization

Tags: c++, linux, caching, profiling

Is there a way to measure cache line utilization? By cache line utilization I mean the fraction of cache line bytes that are read or written before a cache line is evicted. My target is an Intel CPU running Linux. The measurements don't necessarily need to come from the physical CPU itself. A simulation like valgrind uses is fine too.

The motivation is that this could be a useful way to skim code for areas where changing memory layout is worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Intel® VTune™ Amplifier XE 2016](https://software.intel.com/en-us/get-started-with-vtune) may be what you want.

Comment: I've been meaning to try out VTune. Do you know if it actually has this feature?

Comment: Read this: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/cache-miss-rates-in-intel-vtune-amplifier-xe